# I'm looking for the full info on how to install xfce4 from ubuntu mini

Tags: xfce

I have been down with with torn ligaments in my ankle for 7 weeks now, so I'm looking for the full info on to do a mini ubuntu install and not choose any desktop environment. I want to install xfce4 desktop environment with minimal install. I want to install what I want myself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But… the “Xfce4 *desktop environment*” (highlight by me) is a desktop environment as you state yourself. Why not simply download and install Xubuntu? I suspect that this will be exactly what you want. If not, please clarify what you *don't want* that is in a Xubuntu installation but not in a minimal installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the minimal Ubuntu image from the following page (which also has instructions):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

You'll probably want the 16.04 64-bit image, unless you know you need a different version.

Burn it to a DVD or make a USB stick exactly how you would with any other Ubuntu image. Then reboot your computer with the media in the drive, and the text-based installer should start.

The installer does work with most wireless hardware, but it's possible that you will need to plug in an Ethernet cable, if your wireless card isn't properly detected or if you can't connect to your wireless network.

The installer will have a step where you choose installation packages, including desktop environments; you can unselect all desktop environments and choose "Manual package selection" instead.

After the installation is complete, the command-line program "aptitude" (`sudo aptitude`) can also come in handy for installing packages from the command line, resolving dependency issues, etc. I go into its preference menu (F10 activates the menu) and de-select "consider recommended packages as dependencies" for even less bloat.

The keys in aptitude are vim-like, and might be unfamiliar, but the menus are pretty user-friendly. `u` updates the package list, `+` marks a package for installation, `-` un-marks a package for installation (or marks it for removal), and `g` applies changes. `U` marks all upgradeable packages for upgrade. `q` exits the current screen to go back to the previous one. `Actions -> Cancel All Pending Actions` will undo all package markings, in case you selected too many and just want to start from a clean slate.

Then install the appropriate "xfce4-" packages, depending on what you'd like.

This guide might be useful, as well: https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/how-to-install-a-minimal-ubuntu-desktop/

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

--Nick

Comment: Well what I did is installed the mini without making any desktop and then rebooted and held ctrl+F1+alt at grub hit enter and press them real fast. Then I typed sudo apt-get install xfce4 then apt-get install xfce4-goodies then apt-get install xfce4-lightdn apt-get install xfce4-lightdm-greeter and I also installed terminal synaptic and google chrome. And now I'm using it to write this and o yeah I startx to login then resart it and had to put the restart the did the ctsl thing again and it to me to the lightdm and now it boots all the the time on it's own now.

Comment: Very cool! I'm glad you got it working.